# How to define custom List layout in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I notice that `List` does not have something like `CustomLayoutBuilder` and can present data only like `TableView`?

I'd like to know how to create views like this one in `SwiftUI` assuming that the size of a list can be very big:

[image]

I checked tutorial [Composing Complex Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces) but it uses scrollviews.

Answer (score 0):

Tiles layout like you mentioned many not be possible using the Swift UI entirely.
You may be able to combine it with the regular UI kit for better results.

Comment: I hope that the SwiftUI team make it possible. It's possible in Flutter and React.

Answer (score 0):

As for today (06.06.2019), **SwiftUI doesn't have a collection component(equivalent of UICollectionView)**.

Check Joe Groff's comments in this [thread](https://twitter.com/jesse_squires/status/1136341948535435265).